# How to start an application via URL in chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to start my application via Chrome.
The protocol should be like `4chget://<4chan url>` to start my application with `4chget.exe <4chan url>`, but chrome afaik doesn't support own URL protocols(except ...%s) with which I can't start my application, so it is just awkward...

Is there any other way to start my application with given args?

Comment: For Windows, URL Schemes are set at the OS level so you would have to do it in the registry. Android, iOS, Linux,  and Mac will probably have varyng other methods to set schemes. And afaik there are no other methods by which to launch an external application. A plugin using NPAPI might have been able to do it but chrome no longer supports it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yeah, I registerd the protocol in the Win32-registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`

Comment: Then if you've restarted chrome it should work. The first time chrome tries to use it, it should pop up a warning message and wither or not to actually open it. And I believe there is an option in the warning message to make it not ask again.

Comment: Is the URI scheme a requirement? What's your use case? A chrome extension can be used to start a program with arguments, but it cannot (fully reliably) intercept custom URIs.